# Ошибка при работе с динамической памятью

Tags: c++, outofmemoryerror

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class String {
    int len;
    char* str;

public:
    String();
    String(const String &s);
    String(char* str);
    ~String();

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &in, const String &s);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &out, String &s);
};

String::String() {
    len = 0;
    str = new char[len];
}

String::String(const String &s) {
    str = new char[s.len];
    strcpy(this->str, s.str);
    this->len = s.len;
}

String::String(char* str) {
    this->str = new char[strlen(str)];
    strcpy(this->str, str);
    this->len = strlen(str);
}

String::~String() {
    delete[] str;
    len = 0;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const String &s) {
    out << s.str;
    return out;
}

istream & operator>>(istream &in, String &s) {
    char tmp[100001] = {0};
    in.getline(tmp, 100001);
    s.str = new char[strlen(tmp)];
    strcpy(s.str, tmp);
    s.len = strlen(tmp);
    return in;
}

int main() {
    String s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Во время выполнения выдаёт ошибку:
[image: Ошибка]

Подскажите, что это значит и как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this->str = new char[strlen(str)];
strcpy(this->str, str);
```

и везде вы забываете выделять память на один больше- для символа '\0', который должен быть в каждом символьном массиве

Comment: кстати ошибки не только компиляции, но и логические ошибки присутствуют  и лишняя писанина  типа   this->len = s.len; Когда можно просто написать  len = s.len;

Comment: Спасибо, просто ещё не совсем хорошо ориентируюсь в этом

Comment: ничего, никто сразу все не знал ведь...